# Set property value through user input using WIX

Tags: .net, wix, custom-controls, wix3.7

MyWixUI_InstallDir.wxs:

My custom dialog has:

```
      <Control Id="DBServer" Type="Text" X="20" Y="60" Width="290" Height="13" 
       NoPrefix="yes" Text="Name of the SQL Server to deploy the DTA script" />
      <Control Id="DBSText" Type="Edit" X="20" Y="72" Width="290" Height="18" 
       Property="DTAServer" />
```

Product.wxs:

```
         <util:XmlFile Id="AppConfigSetConnStr" Action="setValue" Permanent="yes" File="[INSTALLLOCATION]TestService.exe.config"            
           ElementPath="/configuration/startup/supportedRuntime[\[]@version='v4.0'[\]]" Name="version"
         Value="----" />
```

How can I set the 'value' same as what the user  has entered through the UI or how can i access the property 'DTAServer' in Product.wxs.Kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A global property had to be declared(all alphabets in capital)
e.g

```
  <Property Id="ABC"/>
```

use the same property in Product.wxs and MyWixUI_InstallDir.wxs.

Comment: Thanks for the "all alphabets in capital"! This saved my day!